# I am getting the following JSON error when trying to web scrape dates from Trustpilot with BS4 - Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, trustpilot

I am using the following script to scrape user review data from the Trustpilot website to do some analysis on user sentiment using data from https://ca.trustpilot.com/review/www.hellofresh.ca I expect to scrape

Date, Star Rating,Review Content.

but when i run the code, i am getting the following error, can anyone help explain why?

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

````
stars = []
dates = []
comments = []
results = []
with requests.Session() as s:
    for num in range(1,2):
        url = "https://ca.trustpilot.com/review/www.hellofresh.ca?page={}".format(num)
        r = s.get(url, headers = headers)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')

        for star in soup.find_all("section", {"class":"review__content"}):

            # Get rating value
            rating = star.find("div", {"class":"star-rating star-rating--medium"}).find('img').get('alt')

            # Get date value
            #date_json = json.loads(star.find('script').text)
            #date = date_json['publishedDate']
            
            date_tag = star.select("div.review-content-header__dates > script")    
            date = json.loads(date_tag[0].text)
            dt = datetime.strptime(date['publishedDate'], "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
            
            
            # Get comment
            comment = star.find("div", class_="review-content__body").text

            stars.append(rating)
            dates.append(dt)
            comments.append(comment)

            data = {"Rating": rating, "Review": comment, "Dates": date}
            results.append(data)

        time.sleep(2)


print(results)```
````

Comment: It sounds like there are some instances where `date_tag[0].text` is blank.

Comment: @JohnGordon makes sense. Is there a way to get around this error?

Comment: Check if the tag is blank beforehand, and if so, handle it appropriately.  (Maybe that would mean skipping the entry altogether?  Not sure what your business needs are.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the JSON data, you can call the [`.string`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#string) method.

```
...

date = json.loads(date_tag[0].string)
>>> print(date)
{'publishedDate': '2021-01-04T21:57:34+00:00', 'updatedDate': None, 'reportedDate': None}

...
...
```